# How to add product into shopping cart by single click using custom module in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cart, magento-2.1, addtocart, magento-2.0.7

My template file code is

```
$listBlock = $this->_listBlock;
     $addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($_product);
     ?>
     <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $addToCartUrl; ?>" method="post"> 

    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
    <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary">

       <span>Add to Cart</span>
     </button>
 </form>
```

My Block code is

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Block;
class AddProduct extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

  protected $_productCollectionFactory;
   public $_listBlock;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,

   \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,

    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $listBlock,
    array $data = []
)
{


    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;

    $this->_listBlock = $listBlock;

    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
}
```

Comment: can u please share your block class code?

Comment: I am getting message like **You added Harmony Lumaflex™ Strength Band Kit to your shopping cart.**. But it's not adding to the shopping cart. Please can you guide me, where exactly i'm wrong

Comment: @Pinku Did you get your point?

Answer (score 0):

Need some change at block class

- **change extends class**

  \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template

**to**

```
 \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct
```

Add implements class `Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;`

**Add add to cart function**

```
 public function getAddToCartPostParams(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $url = $this->getAddToCartUrl($product);
        return [
            'action' => $url,
            'data' => [
                'product' => $product->getEntityId(),
                \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED =>
                    $this->urlHelper->getEncodedUrl($url),
            ]
        ];
    }
```

- **Change template file**

change template to `Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml`

**Modified class**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Block;
/* add some class */
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;

class AddProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct implements IdentityInterface
{
....
 public function getAddToCartPostParams(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $url = $this->getAddToCartUrl($product);
        return [
            'action' => $url,
            'data' => [
                'product' => $product->getEntityId(),
                \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED =>
                    $this->urlHelper->getEncodedUrl($url),
            ]
        ];
    }

  public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        return  $this->_productCollectionFactory;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry but i can not change extend class because it will effect my other work. so extend class should be **\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template**

Comment: it my mistake extends class should be ` \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct` and \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template

Comment: can you pls explain me clearly what to extend. I get abstract error